# Where are subscriptions registered in SSMS after creating subscription on Distributor Server?

Tags: sql-server, replication

With 2 servers, each with a SQL Server instance, I can:

1. Create a local publication on server A
2. Create a local Subscription on server B (managed by the Distributor database)

Then on server A I can see the publication. But there is no publication on server B. If I try re-create the same local subscription on server B, then I get an error that the subscription already exists.

Why can I not see the subscription within the subscription folder on Server B?

Server B is also the Distributor server

I think it was a push subscription - i.e. that it was configured on the distributor to be pushed.

I have expanded the publication tree on the publisher and can see the publication. I was expecting the subscription to be seen in the same way. I tried refreshing.

It is on neither publisher nor subscriber. but if I try to recreate the replication then I get an error that it already exists. The question I'm asking is effectively "why can't I see a subscription in the replication folder?"

Alternatively. Is there a SQL Server instance that I need to connect to?

I should note that there are errors in the replication monitor. So there are still a couple problems. Anyway. I can see the jobs in the SQL Server Agent. There was a warning: "Starting the synchronization agent(s)". Would this stop the subscription being created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience a few days later...

When creating a pull subscription, the subscription was added to the 'local subscriptions' folder in SSMS.

When creating a push subscription, nothing is added to the subscription folder until the subscription is run the first time. Thereafter it is added to the 'local subscriptions' folder.